# Integrate login with facebook with cocoa app osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, facebook-graph-api

I have searched it for so long but can't find any proper source of it facebook didn't provide any sdk for it. Do anyone know about how to integrate it with osx app?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **facebook sdk** for cocoa

```
      or
```

https://github.com/philippec/PhFacebook

I hope it is helpful to u

Comment: I have tried it but getting error about invalid redirect uri.. I have set the redirect uri from facebook dev page what they want me to set it.

Comment: I am using the PhFacebook sample code it is working fine for me .just i added the app_id(which is created in Facebook) in ApplicationID.h

Comment: I was missing some configuration in facebook app. We have to set "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" property in app dashboard > settings > advanced to "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" for desktop application to get this done. Else it will always return the invalid redirect uri error. Anyways thanks :)